# Recognize call answer event in Asterisk AMI

Tags: events, asterisk, phone-call, amazon-ami

Which event shall I use to recognize the end of conversation with employee?

There are some events: Unlink, Hangup, Dial (Subevent: End)

As I understood, Unlink event (without following Bridge event) suits best, but it can be fired a lot of times during conversation.
Dial (Subevent: End) and Hangup doesnt fire when call is transferred to another employee.

Answer (score 1):

1) Listen for every bridge event and save uniqueid somewhere. 
2) Then, on every Hangup event, look if you have uniqueid in that list from brigde events.

Hangup event does not fire on transfer because the channel is still active.